# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Phone.Notifications.BasePage.'

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I was trying to implement Push Notification.I was trying based on this Link (http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/11/adding-push-notification-support-to-your-windows-phone-application/) in VisualStudio Express 2012 for windows phone.
When I was installing Package 'Phone.Notifications.BasePage'.
Following error was raising.How can i overcome this.

[image]

And also can anybody please tell me can I add Windows Azure Project.(ASP.Net MVC3 Webrole)to my exiting solution.Which Azure Package wil be supported in VS Express 2012 for windows phone.
Based on this link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683673.aspx) I am thinking WindowsAzurePackage will not be supported in VS Express 2012 for windows phone.I dont have any idea on this(Windows Azure Packages)PUShNotifications.I am Seeking for some help.

ManyThanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Adds a reference to the Azure Service Bus SDK with the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus NuGet package.

This is for 2013 but I am sure it will work in 2012

Look at the end of the following documentation on azures web site

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

This will only work communicating from your MVC project to azure. Not communicating from your phone directly to the notification hub.  You will have to add a rest api to your MVC application and then use RestSharp to send messages to your MVC application from the phone.